# google diff-match-patch library for words using c# or any backend technology

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, google-diff-match-patch

Hi I am using c# libary diff-match-patch. Here I see diff is calculated based on character level, I am looking for diff comparison at word level. Current my below code works at character level

```
 diff_match_patch dmp = new diff_match_patch();
 string s1 = "added";
 string s2 = "edited";
 dmp.diff_main(s1, s2);
```

This code do character by character comparison I am looking word by word comparison? Can someone please let me know does this library works with word by word? C# or any other backend library can someone please suggest, Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `diff_cleanupSemantic` here's the exmple from api wiki:

https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/wiki/Language:-C%23

```
using DiffMatchPatch;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class hello {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    diff_match_patch dmp = new diff_match_patch();
    List<Diff> diff = dmp.diff_main("Hello World.", "Goodbye World.");
    // Result: [(-1, "Hell"), (1, "G"), (0, "o"), (1, "odbye"), (0, " World.")]
    dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff);
    // Result: [(-1, "Hello"), (1, "Goodbye"), (0, " World.")]
    for (int i = 0; i < diff.Count; i++) {
      Console.WriteLine(diff[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Colorized output example:

```
diff_match_patch dmp = new diff_match_patch();
List<Diff> diff = dmp.diff_main("123 Hello World!", "12 GoodBye World");
dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff);
for (int i = 0; i < diff.Count; i++)
{
    // Colorize by operation type
    switch (diff[i].operation)
    {
        case Operation.DELETE:
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            break;
        case Operation.INSERT:
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            break;
        case Operation.EQUAL:
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    Console.Write(diff[i].text);
}
// back to white
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
// html code
string html = dmp.diff_prettyHtml(diff);
// result: <span>12</span><del style="background:#ffe6e6;">3 Hello</del><ins style="background:#e6ffe6;"> GoodBye</ins><span> World</span><del style="background:#ffe6e6;">!</del>
```

Comment: Hi @Nima,  This i tried this does character by character comparison. I am looking for word by word for example String1 is Added and String2 is edited then result should be something like  addededited with added bold or red or some indication and some indication for edited like http://incaseofstairs.com/jsdiff/

Comment: `dmp.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff)` makes word by word. words removed -1, words added 1 and words with no change 0. You can colorize the output by yourself.

Comment: Hi @Nima can you pls give 12 is source and target as 123 as input to above program and can you pls tell me out put? Or source Added and Destination Edited and can you please tell me output? I am bit confused

Comment: @Niranjan It's not like jsdiff and result is different. I'll edit the answer and add an example.

Comment: Sure @Nima. Thanks